# Pandas - How to drop non-duplicates for multi-indexed values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkFN7.png)

I want to keep the values that have different Index 1 values, but the same Index 2 values. So, it'll look like this: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7t7y.png)

Any ideas on how to do this? All help is very much appreciated.

Edit: To give a clearer answer, for three-level indexing in data frames in pandas: how do I count the number of the second-level indexes for each first level index? And if the number of second-level indexes is 1, how do I drop that row?

Comment: provide the code please

Comment: Not clear what you want to filter, in the pictures provided it seems like you rows 3 and 4 also contains the same index 1 value, are you sure thats the desired output, if so can you please provide more detail on what you want

Comment: Unfortunately, given the nature of the data, I can't provide the code @Kushim Yes! Rows 3 and 4 are supposed to be the same.

Comment: Essentially, I want to keep any values that have different Index 1 values but have the same Index 2 values.

Comment: But rows 3 and 4 in your image both have the same index1 value

Comment: Or when you say different, different from what?

Comment: I made on edit on the original post — I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think the solution might look like, provide any feedback in case you need something else please :)

```
# Setting up test case
data = {'index_1': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'index_2': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'value': [121, 123, 4345, 2323, 232345, 21]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['index_1', 'index_2'])

# Querying based on condition
df.query('index_2 != 1')
```